log log representation
I have two questions:

Is there any nicer way of writing $\log \log (x)$, rather than writing log twice? I googled this and it appears there isn't, but just to double-check.

If $x$ and $y$ are positive real numbers, if $\log(x)/\log(y)>t$ for some constant $t$, does it always follow that we also have $\log\log(x)/\log\log(y)>t$?



(2) is really just asking if $\log x/\log y\geq \log\log x/\log\log y.$ This is obviously not true, since if it is true (but not equal) for $(x,y),$ then it is not true for $(x',y')=(y,x).$

You might be able to prove some version of $(2)$ with the condition that $x>y.$

No, it is not even true when $x>y.$


Why not $\log(\log(x))$? Looks good to me. You also write $f(f(x))$.



There is no widespread standard notation for this. Mathematicians really enjoy writing out their log's ( E.g. https://arxiv.org/abs/1408.5110 )


@ThomasAndrews sorry I didn't understand your argument, do you mind explaining it?

If you want clarification, be more specific about what confused you. If I wanted to write a full answer, I would have. My argument was an outline.

Normally with functions, you denote by $f^n$ the composition $\underbrace{f\circ f\circ\cdots\circ f}_{n\,\mathrm{times}}$. So, you can use $\log^n$. But due to the (unfortunate) convention of $\sin^2$, that may be confusing. Even then, if you specify beforehand what you mean, it is okay to use the notation. But then again, it is not standard, so you maybe want to stick with the lengthier notation.
For the second part, recall that $\log$ is a strictly increasing, so indeed if $\log x>\log y$, then $\log\log x>\log\log y$ (though you need to ensure $x>1$ to make sense of $\log\log x$).
Hope this helps. :)

I just realized how stupid my second question is, thanks - of course log is an increasing function.
